# preg_replace() - removing a string contained within html tags

Tags: php, string

I want to do the following:

I have a string in a database, it is stored with html tags when being inserted there, so for example, I might have the following string:

```
     <h2>Hello World</h2>
     <p>Cras mattis justo vitae diam sagittis ut porta eros aliquam. 
        Aenean vel nisi et nisl adipiscing blandit. 
        Donec tempor dictum risus a feugiat. 
        Nunc ac purus lectus. Morbi in suscipit ipsum. 
        Ut eu odio eu massa sollicitudin interdum. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Maecenas fermentum hendrerit imperdiet.</p>
```

This is a string I might have in the database, and I want to discard the `<h2>` part of it.

Now, as far as I know, doing a preg_replace() here, would do the job, but what string pattern do I need to look for?

Many thanks.

Comment: Parsing might be better then replacing: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If your HTML is relatively simple, a regex might be able to cope with it.  For general HTML, though you should look into using a parser instead of a regex to deal with it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @yes123: Don't assert; explain!

Comment: @tomalak: you stalk me really. anyway just to contradict once again DRY: don't use simplehtmldom use a proper xml parser not one based on strings.

Comment: @yes123: DRY, as a principle, is a great idea in a locality. But relying on DRY for something that you might have explained somewhere, once upon a time, in a far-away answer to a far-away question is pretty useless without providing an URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Remove HTML Tags](http://davebrooks.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/php-preg_replace-some-useful-regular-expressions/) section on the linked site.  E.g.

```
@<h2[^>]*?>.*?</h2>@siu
```

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer your question the replace method RegEx would be:

```
/<h2>(.+?)<\/h2>/
```

However, as the comments pointed out, this isn't the best method! :)

Answer (score 1):

Nice by **Michael Wright**.

Another way to solve this problem using **strip_tags()** function.

```
  $patern = '<p>';
  $str = '<h2>Hello World</h2><p>Cras mattis justo vitae diam .</p>';
  strip_tags($str,$patern);
```

This code generate the following output

```
 'Hello World<p>Cras mattis justo vitae diam .</p>'
```

Here $pattrn contain the tag list that still remain in you data. strip_tags() eliminates all tags except in $patern.

[reference from php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)